# Did they block Whatsapp Web on mobile browsers?

Tags: whatsapp

I am pretty sure that I successfully connected to Whatsapp Web from a mobile browser an  year or two back. I opened the site [www.web.whatsapp.com](http://www.web.whatsapp.com), the usual desktop interface showed up, and I scanned the QR code using a whatsapp account on *another* phone, and I was logged in from the mobile browser just as I'd be from a desktop browser.
When I try it these days, as of 2020, it doesn't happen. The url [www.web.whatsapp.com](http://www.web.whatsapp.com) is automatically and invariably redirected to [www.whatsapp.com](http://www.whatsapp.com).

Did they purposely block this avenue, or is it something to do with my devices?

Was this feature undesirable to Whatsapp in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell your browser to open it as a desktop site.

On **iPhone**: click on Aa letters in the browser and click "Request Desktop Website".

On **Android**: click on three dots in the URL section and check "Desktop site".

Comment: Ohh. You're spot on! I feel so stupid for having missed this simple thing.